# Does the file input type provide a reasonable call to action?

Tags: usability, guidelines, file-input

I have a use case where a user wants to convert a text file, from one format to another. This may however not always be the same user, effectively anyone could be left instructions telling them.

1. Download the file from the FTP Server.
2. Convert the file. (My [app](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32332055/concat/index.html) comes in here...)
3. Upload the file to a database.

Does a file input button, serve well enough as a call to action, or should I provide on screen instructions?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Rather than reviewing this particular implementation, which is a bit confusing, can you describe the actual problem that you were trying to solve with this implementation? (You've described a solution without defining what the problem itself was)

Comment: Edited the question @JonW. Hope that is a better fit for ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose some improvements, based on the [usability heuristics](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/). The main issue here is the absence of clear focal point which leads to the convertion task execution.

Also the task itself could be fully automated, there no man needed. Just provide FTP address and access parameters to a database. And let it run as batch process.

[image]

Comment: "Cancel" would be more appropriate than "Break".

Comment: Nice ideas thanks. I can't provide the next step as you need to login to a sales databases control centre webpages and select the file to upload and configure the line endings etc.... Theres no api for this sadly.

Comment: is it not better to autosave the file ? rather than prompt the user for another click.

Comment: @Luke 1) ZZZ is a link to login page on DB control centre. 2) Autosave could be easily missed by a user as it's background process. And you couldn't provide feedback on the page where on a HDD the file was saved. Missed autosaved file lead to user confusion and he'll repeat the entire process from the beginning again and again. Having link user is able to save file later, it's a convenient solution.